# Radon-Nikodym Derivatives between Ito Processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, radon-nikodym

I am curious about the following problem:

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathcal F_t, \mathbb P_a)$, where the filtration is generated by $B_t$. On a finite interval $[0,T]$ we define $X_t$ as the one solving the SED
$$\mathrm dX_t=\mu_a\,\mathrm dt+\sigma\,\,\mathrm dB_t.$$
For some other measure $\mathbb P_b$, we define $X_t$ as the solution to
$$\mathrm dX_t=\mu_b\,\mathrm dt+\sigma\,\mathrm d B_t',$$
where $B_t'$ is a Brownian motion under $\mathbb P_b$, $\mu_a\ne\mu_b$ being two different real numbers, and $\sigma>0$ being a constant. Hence, the difference between the two diffusion processes lies only in the drift.

My question is: what is the Radon-Nikodym derivate (as a function of $t$ and $X_t$)
$$\frac{\mathrm d\mathbb P_a}{\mathrm d\mathbb P_b}$$ 
on $\{\mathcal F_t\}$? What I know so far is the answer to a special case: $\mu_a=0$, where the answer can be derived explicitly. Is it possible to generalize the special case? Many thanks!

Comment: Apply the result you say you know, *twice*, once to pass from drift $\mu_b$ to drift $0$ and once to pass from drift $0$ to drift $\mu_a$.

Comment: And why would anyone want to apply a result twice when once is sufficient? That is very, very confusing to me.

Comment: @ArbiasHashani Sorry, what was that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is the **Girsanov theorem**.

With some technical conditions, the Radon Nikodym derivative is given be

$ \frac{ \mathrm{d}  \mathbb{P}_b}{\mathrm{d} \mathbb{P}_a} (\omega) = \exp \left(  \int_0^T h_s(\omega) \, \mathrm{d}B_s(\omega) - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^T h_s(\omega)^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \right) $,

where $h$ is a (progressively measurable) function to be found. With some technical conditions it is not difficult to find $h$.

Comment: Arbias Hashani, are you sure you don't mean the converse of the Girsanov? [Given Q and Xt is Q-Brownian, find dQdP / Uniqueness of Brownian or Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579205)